# snowflake stored procedure and task issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake task runs in a separate session ? when the stored procedure is called manually  it could access the session parameter but when the same stored procedure is called through tasks ,it cannot access the session variables

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you manually run a task then it will run in your session. If you schedule a task it will run in its own session